# Javascript settimeouts with IE8

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, xmlhttprequest

With this Javascript code, I get this error "Object does not support this property or method" error.  I checked that the methods are available and I do a check that the method is there.  Am I sending the wrong number of args?  Has anyone used this?

```
var xmlServerHttp = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0");
var lResolve = 5 * 1000;
var lConnect = 5 * 1000;
var lSend = 15 * 1000;
var lReceive = 15 * 1000;
xmlServerHttp.setTimeouts(lResolve, lConnect, lSend, lReceive);
xmlServerHttp.open("GET", "http://localhost/sample.xml", false);
xmlServerHttp.send();
```

Comment: setTimeout is a window method- an ActiveXObject can't call it, even if it was spelled correctly.

Comment: @kennebec: I think Berlin is talking about [this `setTimeouts` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms760403%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: I can't reproduce this.  I put your code in an HTML file, opened it in IE9, and didn't get any errors.

Comment: It was on IE8.  I guess IE8 doesn't have this method.